# What is the benefit of caching an IReader?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, caching

Reviewing some legacy code, there is a commonally used table that gets updated very infrequently.

To save having to constantly go to the database to get the same data each time, it seems like the developer was trying to cache the data. The code looks like this:

```
    private static IDataReader _cachedCheckList;
    public override IDataReader GetDataReader()
    {
        if (_cachedCheckList == null)
        {
            using (var oneTimeRead = base.GetDataReader())
            {
                _cachedCheckList = new CachedDataReader(oneTimeRead);
            }
        }
        return _cachedCheckList ?? base.GetDataReader();
    }
```

Then elsewhere in the system the function that uses this follows the pattern of:

```
        IDataReader reader = new CheckList().GetDataReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            [snip]
        }
```

By loading the IReader into memory, I don't think that this provides much in the way of a performance increase.

I'm trying to understand the developers reason for this code. What is the benefit of caching the IReader?

---

Update: The CachedDataReader() method is basically:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
return command.ExecuteReader();
```

I'd not seen anyone cache a DataReader before and was wondering there was a good reason to do this before refactoring the code.

Comment: Reading data from IO is many times more expensive than reading from memory.  With that said the benefits are completely based on how often the data is accessed.  The down side is that the cached data can become stale.

Comment: @juharr - the `DataReader` is being cached, not the data. OP is asking why cache the `DataReader` itself.

Comment: @DigiFriend We have no idea what's being cached since we don't have the code for `CachedDataReader`.  Caching a `DataReader` would be really really dumb, so I gave the creator of the code the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @juharr - the OP seems to suggest that's what is going on, which is _why they are asking the question in the first place_.

Comment: @DigiFriend I took _loading the IReader into memory_ to mean that it reads the data into memory, not that it just keeps a reference to the `DataReader`.  If it were doing that there wouldn't be a need for another class, just stick the `DataReader` into a global variable.  Long story short we will not know unless the OP gives us the missing code.

Comment: Must likely `CachedDataReader` read the data from the underlying datareader into memory and then just provides that data (in memory) as a datareader  to the consumer. But without seeing the code for that class we can not know.
One potential danger I see here is that there is no locking while setting the `_cachedCheckList` property.

Answer (score -1):

May be
they used DataReader cache for following reasons and they are as follows :-
DataReader  readonly and forward only. It fetches the record from databse and stores in the network buffer and gives whenever requests. DataReader release the records as query executes and do not wait for the entire query to execute. Therefore it is very fast as compare to the dataset. It releases only when read method is called.

> DataReader should not be Cached. You should fetch data in DataSet or DataTable and then use:
>
> ```
> Cache["Data"] = DataTable;
> ```
>
> Never cache DataReader objects. Because a DataReader object holds an open connection to the database, caching the object extends the lifetime of the connection, affecting other users of the database. Also, because theDataReader is a forward-only stream of data, after a client has read the information, the information cannot be accessed again. Caching it would be futile.
>
> Caching DataReader objects disastrously affects the scalability of your applications. You may hold connections open and eventually cache all available connections, making the database unusable until the connections are closed. Never cache DataReader objects no matter what caching technology you are using.

Above quotes taken from https://forums.asp.net/post/3224692.aspx

Comment: OP seems to understand what caching is and why it is used. OP is unclear on why this caching of a `DataReader` is done, as it is just the reader, not the data.